# Why neither netbeans nor PHP reports error from this code

Tags: php

Why do neither netbeans nor PHP report an error from this code:

```
public function __construct ()
{
global $blog;
$this->_blog_id = $blog->blog_id;
$this->_post_amount = $blog->
$this->_limit_per_page = $blog->config_get('posts_limit_per_page');
$this->_short_sign_limit = $blog->config_get('posts_short_sign_limit');
}
```

I had a phone call and forgot about that unfinished 3rd line, saved my work and website silently died on it.

Comment: Why do you put untested code in production?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster *Its called Agile development.*

Comment: its on my private dev server, on top of it im only developer;) anyway, thanks for care:)

Comment: Oh, and if your website "silently died" you should configure your dev server's PHP to `display_errors=on` and `error_reporting=E_ALL` via php.ini

Comment: i have it, i checked logs (it goes to separate log which i tail -f in ssh session as well, and nothing>,<), thats like first time i saw something like this - thats why i asked question:)

Comment: i found where it stored error info - /var/log/messages ;) Sep 24 13:35:14 server kernel: httpd[7117]: segfault at 00007fffb4dfeff8 rip 00002ae22492ff25 rsp 00007fffb4dff000 error 6, so instead of showing php error or something - it segfaulted silently in the middle of processing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->_post_amount = $blog->
$this->_limit_per_page = $blog->config_get('posts_limit_per_page');
```

can also be written as

```
$this->_post_amount = $blog->$this->_limit_per_page = $blog->config_get('posts_limit_per_page');
```

which makes no sense but is perfectly valid.

However, in your case it breaks your script because using `$instance->$other_instance` without a `__toString` method results in this error: `Object of class Test could not be converted to string`. You IDE does not check for this since since it's really an edge case and as soon as it's not `$this->$this` but e.g. `$this->$that` with `$that` being e.g. the return value of another function it would be near impossible to know what `$that` can be.

---

Here's some example code that proves how `$this->$this` can actually work fine:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public $foo = 'bar';
}

class Test {
    private $xyz;
    function __construct() {
        $this->xyz = new Foo();
    }
    function __toString() {
        return 'xyz';
    }
    function run() {
        echo $this->$this->foo;
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->run();
```

The `$this->$this` statement will result in `__toString` being used for the second `$this` and thus it will be equivalent to `$this->xyz` so the whole line will end up as `echo $this->xyz->foo;` which is valid.

Comment: okie, then if its valid - why script stopped there and didnt continue to other parts, like it would do die();

Comment: Because in your case `$this->$this` does not result in anything useful and thus trying to access a property on this non-object will crash your script.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are technically doing

```
$this->_post_amount = $blog->{$this->_limit_per_page} = $blog->config_get('posts_limit_per_page');
```

Which is valid.